# Hotkey to direct Control-V + a script to the focused window?

Tags: scripts, shortcut-keys

I need to define a hotkey that does a paste to the focused window, followed by (in my case), `/usr/bin/diodon pop`, which pops from diodon's clipboard manager list.  So effectively, the hotkey should do: `Control-V; my_script`. I tried `xsel -o` and `xclip -o` to do the paste, but they didn't work.  Any other ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use `xdotool`.  To get it to work with an added script in a hotkey, it has to be done this way:

```
/bin/bash -c "xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+v && /usr/bin/diodon pop"
```